# Disable screen shot in my android app

Tags: android, google-maps, screenshot

I have my current android application which **do not allow user to take screen shot**.

**I am using** `getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);` **in my onCreate() method** and working perfectly fine.

Now my problem is in one of my screen I am navigating user to Google map with some routes. I don't want user to take screen shot in that screen too. My current implementation disables user to take screen shot from my app. But I don't want that user can take screen shot of Google Map too when he goes from my app. Is there any solution for this or any work around. Any help will b highly appreciated.

Comment: Don't waste your time with such silly requirements.  If the user really wanted to preserve information, they can write down their location, use another map application to figure it out or simply take a picture of their phone with another.  All you accomplish by trying to do this is to develop a reputation for annoying, anti-user design.

Comment: And how can u say that what my requirement is? Simply by making few comment without knowing what others requirement is, aren't u try to build some kindda repo??

Comment: @ChrisStratton Making things slightly more inconvenient to minimize the frequency of some undesired result is not silly.  Not all devices are being used by end users with the expectation that all functionality will be available.  Consider a tablet being used by employees for some specific function in a warehouse or as a point of sale system.

Comment: That's not the case here, but again, if the user wants the information they can write it down on paper or their palm or take a picture of the screen with another device.  This just goes to show how anti-user measures serve no purpose other than to give the developer a bad reputation.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of prompting the 3rd party app, consider using a [MapActivity](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapActivity).

Then you can you can place a MapView in the layout and show the Map.
In this case, you will be able to control the restriction via the secure flag.

Just place the same code in the onCreate() method like you did on the other activity.

Comment: I am quite doubt full whether i will be able to use MapActivity as there are two or three places where i am navigating user to Google map. I may have to check few more test case scenario and at this point of time I can't afford major code change. Can't there me some work aruond??

Comment: You can just startactivity(your_map_activity) from those few places. Just a suggestion. I have no idea how to prevent screenshot for a third party app at the moment. :)