# Disable screen capture functionality

Tags: android, screenshot, layoutparams

I know that we can suppress screen capture functionality using the code

```
getWindow( ).setFlags( LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE );
```

But, In my case I have a library, and on a button click I call a method from Library and that method launches new activity. Now, I want to disable screen capture on the newly launched activity, but I cant add this line on newly launched activity since it is launched through library. How can I do that ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable screen shot in my andorid app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597658/disable-screen-shot-in-my-andorid-app)

Comment: No, its not a duplicate. I want to set screen capture disabled on an activity which is launched through library. I do not have library code access, so I cant add the code into it

Comment: You and the op of the other question both don't have access to the code/behaviour of the launched activity. In this regard you have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved. In my case library provides an API through which I can have access to launched activity, so I added the essential line into onCreate() of it. 
Thanks :)

Comment: @Gaurav- Can you tell me , whether you were trying to disable screenshot just on your app or completely on the android phone?Are you able to disable the screenshot functioning even if your app is running in background. Thanks.

Comment: I was trying to disable screenshot, when my app is running on foreground.